# FileManager.default.enumerator does not return any files

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in swift 3.0.2 using XCode 8.2 and I am trying to recursively list the files that are shared with the iOS app through itunes.

At the moment, the following code works:

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
print(documentsUrl.absoluteString)
    
do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print(directoryContents)
        
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

However, the documentation for contentsOfDirectory located [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1414584-contentsofdirectory) states that the function only performs a shallow traversal of the URL and suggests a function that does a deep traversal of the URL, namely enumerator, whose documentation is located [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1409571-enumerator).

I am using the following snippet to try and list all files under the current URL using deep traversal:

```
let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
print(documentsUrl.absoluteString)

let dirContents = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsUrl.resolvingSymlinksInPath(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
print(dirContents.debugDescription)
while let element = dirContents?.nextObject() as? String {
    print(element)
}
```

The issue is that while the first snippet does display file URLs the second one does not display anything.

Could somebody please advise on what could I do to fix that? I would really like to use the second snippet rather than attempt a workaround using the first function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FileManager` has two methods to obtain a directory enumerator:

- [`enumerator(atPath path: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1408726-enumerator)
- [`enumerator(at url: URL, ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/2765464-enumerator)

The first one returns an enumerator which enumerates *strings*
(the file paths), the second one returns an enumerator which
enumerates *URLs.*

Your code uses the URL-based enumerator, therefore the conditional
casts to `as? String` fail and no output is produced.

You have to cast to `URL` instead:

```
if let dirContents = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsUrl.resolvingSymlinksInPath(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil) {

    while let url = dirContents.nextObject() as? URL {
        print(url.path)
    }
}
```

You can also iterate with a for-loop:

```
if let dirContents = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: documentsUrl.resolvingSymlinksInPath(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil) {

    for case let url as URL in dirContents {
        print(url.path)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also cast `allObjects as? [URL] ?? []` Is there any reason for not casting it all together ?

Comment: @LeoDabus: The above does a (lazy) enumeration without creating an array with all objects, so that can be a performance advantage. – The *real* problem is that the API should return an enumerator of URLs in the first place (I think that has been discussed in the Swift forum somewhere).

Comment: IMO the only advantage would be when not iterating all objects. Are you talking about not having all urls in an array (Memory consumption)? What if the user intent is to list them? Whouldnt be better to cast them instead of appending one by one?

Comment: @LeoDabus: If you want an array with all urls then it probably makes no difference (`allObjects` does an enumeration of the objects as well, I assume). But if you just want to iterate over (a part of) the file system (e.g. to find files with certain properties, or to process certain files) then I *assume* that the above approach is more efficient memory-wise.

Answer (score -1):

we can iterate over all URLs with an enumerator and return valid file URLs using the below method

```
func extractFileURLs(from directory: String = "JsonData", withExtension fileExtension: String = "json") -> [URL] {
        var jsonFileURLs: [URL] = []
        if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(
            at: Bundle.main.bundleURL, // replace url if using another bundle
            includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isRegularFileKey],
            options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]
        ) {
            for case let fileURL as URL in enumerator where fileURL.pathExtension == fileExtension {
                jsonFileURLs.append(fileURL)
            }
        }
        guard !jsonFileURLs.isEmpty else {
            assertionFailure("Please verify directory name or file extension")
        }
        return jsonFileURLs
    }
```