# FileManager.fileExists (is item at path a file or directory) not working for me

Tags: swift

Can someone please point out my mistake?

I'm attempting to dig recursively through a directory to just get an array of the files within.
The code I've posted seem to regard every item it sees as a file, including the directories.

(My original code snippet had a misplaced bracket. It still isn't working properly as edited.)

Thanks for the help.

```
    func getAllFiles(atDirectoryPath dirPath: String) {
        
        do {
            let paths = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dirPath)
            
            for p in paths {
                print("looking at \(p)")
                var isDir : ObjCBool = false
                if fm.fileExists(atPath: p, isDirectory: &isDir) {
                    
                    if isDir.boolValue {
                        // is a directory
                        print("\(p) is a directory")
                        getAllFiles(atDirectoryPath: p)
                    } else {
                        // is a file
                        print("\(p) is a file")
                        if fm.displayName(atPath: p) != ".DS_Store" {
                            allFiles.append(p)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } catch {}
        
    }
        
    }
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that `contentsOfDirectory(atPath:)` returns an array containing only the file names relative to the current directory. You would have to concatenate it to the directory path (`let fullPath = dirPath + "/" + p`) to make it work. Working with URLs instead (as demonstrated below) is the recommended approach though.

Comment: For an alternative, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237296/1187415.

Comment: Thanks so much @MartinR.
Just before reading your post I came to the realization that I as only looking at filenames and not entire paths.

Thanks for bringing the url approach to my attention.